# Redirect all non resolved endpoints to a specific registered service

Tags: spring, cloud, spring-cloud, gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to redirect all endpoints (which are not resolved by service-discovery) route to a specific url/lb.

I have a spring cloud gateway server configured to resolve every `/api` request to via Eureka.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          lowerCaseServiceId: true
          enabled: true
          predicates:
            - name: Path
              args:
                pattern: "'/api/'+serviceId.toLowerCase()+'/**'"
          filters:
            - name: RewritePath
              args:
                regexp: "'/api/' + serviceId.toLowerCase() + '/(?<remaining>.*)'"
                replacement: "'/${remaining}'"
```

There is another frontend service too deployed and registered in Eureka. My goal is to route everything else to this frontend service. I tried adding the following route to do so:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          lowerCaseServiceId: true
          enabled: true
          predicates:
            - name: Path
              args:
                pattern: "'/api/'+serviceId.toLowerCase()+'/**'"
          filters:
            - name: RewritePath
              args:
                regexp: "'/api/' + serviceId.toLowerCase() + '/(?<remaining>.*)'"
                replacement: "'/${remaining}'"
      routes:
        - id: frontend
          order: -1
          uri: lb://frontend
          predicates:
            - name: Path
              args:
                pattern: "^((?!api).)*$"
```

But it didn't worked.

**Any idea on how to route everything else that is not discovered in eureka to a specific service/url?**

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          lowerCaseServiceId: true
          enabled: true
          predicates:
            - name: Path
              args:
                pattern: "'/api/'+serviceId.toLowerCase()+'/**'"
          filters:
            - name: RewritePath
              args:
                regexp: "'/api/' + serviceId.toLowerCase() + '/(?<remaining>.*)'"
                replacement: "'/${remaining}'"
      routes:
        - id: frontend
          order: 10
          uri: lb://frontend
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
```